# How to click a button to create many buttons in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, button

I hope that every time the "Create Button" button is clicked, a new button will be created, with a maximum of 8 buttons in each column, and then continue to click the "Create Button" button, and new buttons will be created in the second column, and so on , the effect I want to achieve is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XfR8.jpg)

But currently I'm limited, it's something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RozCG.png)

Here is my **MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Helloone.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Helloone"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid x:Name="grid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Create Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button1_Click" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is my **MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
namespace Helloone
{
 /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private int buttonCount = 1;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a new button
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Content = "Button " + buttonCount.ToString();

            button.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            button.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            button.Margin = new Thickness(10);

            // Add the new button to the Grid
            int row = (buttonCount - 1) / 3 + 1;
            int column = (buttonCount - 1) % 3;
            grid.Children.Add(button);
            Grid.SetRow(button, row);
            Grid.SetColumn(button, column);

            // Increment the button count
            buttonCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add the event `grid_Loaded` for the grid
2. Get nbr of columns
3. Create StackPanel in each columns/Rows..

   ```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
      private int numBut = 0;
      private List<StackPanel> stP = new List<StackPanel>();

     public MainWindow()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
     }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (numBut >= 8 * stP.Count) return;

        var col = numBut / 8;
        var st = stP[col];

        Button button = new Button();
        button.Content = $"Button {++numBut}";
        button.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        button.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        button.Margin = new Thickness(10);
        Grid.SetRow(button, 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(button, col);
        st.Children.Add(button);
    }

    private void grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var nbCols = grid.ColumnDefinitions.Count;

        for (var c = 0; c < nbCols; c++)
        {
            StackPanel st = new StackPanel();
            st.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
            Grid.SetRow(st, 1);
            Grid.SetColumn(st, c);
            grid.Children.Add(st);
            stP.Add(st);
        }
     }
   }
   ```

---

result:

[image]

Comment: I also want to ask further, how to automatically save the last added button when the form is started next time?

Comment: you cant keep because the button have been created dynamically but if yyou want to keep the numbers of buttons created and reproduce the last view at the next start yes its possible but i suggest you to open a new question... to avoid to pollute here...SO is one question for one post